# Sap hana studio how to alter a datetime field to always have the current date

Tags: hana, hana-studio

as the title says, how do i make this field to show me, as default, the current date? I was trying to use this command:

```
ALTER TABLE "SBO_JC_TST"."ORDR"
ALTER (U_Competencia TIMESTAMP, DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE)
```

but it keep giving me this error:

```
Could not execute 'ALTER TABLE "SBO_JC_TST"."ORDR" ALTER (U_Competencia TIMESTAMP, DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE)'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "CURRENT_DATE": line 2 col 41 (at pos 74)
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried changing this field through the compiler but it was too no avail. I guess probally i'm using the wrong expression

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it, what do you guys think?

i used this code instead!

```
ALTER TABLE "SBO_JC_TST"."ORDR"
ALTER ("U_Competencia" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE)
```